# How to display the table by checking the checkbox using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to display a table when the checkbox is checked but it is not working. Below you may find my script, checkbox and table

```
    <script>
    function checked() {
        var checkBox = document.getElementById("check");
        var concession = document.getElementById("hidden");
        if (checkBox.checked == true){
            concession.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            concession.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

<input type = "checkbox" name = "discount" id = "check" onclick = "checked()">

<table id = "hidden" class = "center" style = "display:none">
        <tr>
            <th>102-2 Taxable income is reduced by 400AZN</th>
            <th></th>
            <th><input type = "radio" name = "400"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>102-3 Taxable income is reduced by 200AZN</th>
            <th></th>
            <th><input type = "radio" name = "200"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>102-4 Taxable income is reduced by 100AZN</th>
            <th></th>
            <th><input type = "radio" name = "100"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>102-5 Taxable income is reduced by 50AZN</th>
            <th></th>
            <th><input type = "radio" name = 50"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: There is a typo there in the last input: `name = 50"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this issue as `checked` is a reserved name. Try to rename the function name to something else like `OnCheckboxClicked` to fix this issue.

**DEMO:**

```js
function OnCheckboxClicked() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("check");
  var concession = document.getElementById("hidden");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    concession.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    concession.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="discount" id="check" onclick="OnCheckboxClicked()">

<table id="hidden" class="center" style="display:none">
  <tr>
    <th>102-2 Taxable income is reduced by 400AZN</th>
    <th></th>
    <th><input type="radio" name="400"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>102-3 Taxable income is reduced by 200AZN</th>
    <th></th>
    <th><input type="radio" name="200"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>102-4 Taxable income is reduced by 100AZN</th>
    <th></th>
    <th><input type="radio" name="100"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>102-5 Taxable income is reduced by 50AZN</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name=5 0 "></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

when you use inline handlers like `onclick` you need to assign a function, so `onclick="checked"` is the correct way

As a side note assigning an event via `addEventListener()` should be preferred

```
<input type="checkbox" name="discount" id="check">
<table id="hidden" class="center" style="display:none">
  ...
</table>

<script>
var concession = document.getElementById("hidden");
document.getElementById("check").addEventListener('click', function() {        
    concession.style.display = (this.checked)? "block" : "none";
});
</script>
```

---

Finally, it's worth noting that JS is not necessary at all, since you could use only CSS for this kind of task with the given markup

```
#check + table { display: none }
#check:checked + table { display: block }
```

Comment: We also need to add this in DOMContentLoaded method.

Comment: not necessarily, just be sure to have the element defined in the DOM before using it in JS

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `checked()` is restricted, change the name of your function:

```js
function changed() {
  var checked = document.getElementById("check").checked;
  var concession = document.getElementById("hidden");
  if (checked) {
    concession.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    concession.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="discount" id="check" onChange="changed()">

<table id="hidden" class="center" style="display:none">
  <tr>
    <th>102-2 Taxable income is reduced by 400AZN</th>
    <th></th>
    <th><input type="radio" name="400"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>102-3 Taxable income is reduced by 200AZN</th>
    <th></th>
    <th><input type="radio" name="200"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>102-4 Taxable income is reduced by 100AZN</th>
    <th></th>
    <th><input type="radio" name="100"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>102-5 Taxable income is reduced by 50AZN</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="50"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to add an event listener to the checkbox:

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("#check");

checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
var concession = document.getElementById("hidden");
    if(this.checked) {
         concession.style.display='block';
    } else {
      concession.style.display='none';
    }
});
```